# Creating thumbnail from existing base64 image

Tags: javascript, angular, image, resize, base64

This is my first time using HTML canvas. I have been given a working camera that returns images as a base64 string. I am trying to pass this string to a new function that handles the image resizing(the actual dimensions aren't important right now as I am just testing the resizing).

Right now I am getting a blank image from my generateThumbnail function. Below I have attached an image of the output in the application, as well as an image of the console output. 
For the first attached image, you will see 2 photos. The photo on the left is the original which is working correctly (it is all black because my webcam is covered). The photo on the right is the blank output when I attempt to resize.

```js
generateThumbnail(imageData) {    
  let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  let img = new Image();
  img.onload = () => {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 300, 300);
  }
  img.src = imageData;

  let dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

  console.log(imageData);
  console.log(dataUrl);
  return dataUrl;
}
```

[image of taken photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdufY.png)

[image of console output from thumbnail base64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q43TR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Although your code is not working on the embedded fiddle, I think your problem is because the image has not loaded yet as you're returning `dataUrl` as soon as you execute your method.

```
dataUrl
```

should be returning inside `img.onload` method , maybe something like this will work?

** EDIT **

Make sure you set width and height of your canvas as well.

```js
const generateThumbnail = (imageData) => {    
  let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = 300;
  canvas.height = 300;
  document.querySelector(".canvas").appendChild(canvas);
  
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  let img = new Image();
  
  img.onload = () => {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0 , 0, 300, 300);
     console.log(imageData);
  console.log(dataUrl);
  return dataUrl;
  }
   img.src = imageData;
  let dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  document.querySelector(".image").appendChild(img);
  
}

window.onload = () => { 
generateThumbnail(window.image_base64);
}
```

```css
.canvas, .image { 
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  color: white;
}

.image { border: solid 1px white; }
.canvas { 
  left: 310px;
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

body { 
 background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="canvas"></div>



<script>

window.image_base64 = "data:image/png;base64,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";

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately this is not working either. In fact, it may even be worse. The image is still empty, but also not recognizing the size specified (300 x 300).

Comment: That is very strange, let me make a jsfiddle to test this out. Will update my answer with solution